# Typescript Nested Tagged/Discriminated Union Types

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following types (syntax is Elm-ish/Haskell-ish):

```
type Reply = LoginReply | LogoutReply
type LoginReply = LoginSucceeded | AlreadyLoggedIn String
```

If I try to model it using Typescript's discriminated unions, I'll face the problem that `LoginReply` needs to have a property `kind` with value "loginReply" but it can't because it's declared using `type` keyword, not `class`.

That's my best shot at the problem till now:

```
type Reply = LoginReply | LogoutReply

type LoginReply = LoginSucceeded | AlreadyLoggedIn

interface LoginSucceeded {
  kind: "loginSucceeded";
}

interface AlreadyLoggedIn {
  kind: "alreadyLoggedIn";
  loggedInUsername: string;
}

interface LogoutReply {
  kind: "logoutReply";
}
```

As you can see, one can't even use `"loginReply"` anywhere and thus can't be used in discrimination.

The only workaround I have for knowing a `Reply` variable is a `LoginReply` is to see if its `kind` is one of `"loginSucceeded"` and `"alreadyLoggedIn"`.

So, how do I achieve what I want in Typescript? **How to create a discriminated union type whose child types are discriminated-union types themselves?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will keep this answer for all solutions. Please, update if you have another solution.

---

**Solution#1**: As described in the question, see if `kind` is one of `"loginSucceeded"` and `"alreadyLoggedIn"`.

---

**Solution#2**: As described by [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51744918/6690391), use `kind` and `subKind`.

---

**Solution#3**:

If one argues that **Solution#2** makes `LoginSucceeded` and `AlreadyLoggedIn` know too much about them being discriminated types of discriminated types, one could also argue that, even under one level of discrimination, they shouldn't have had knowledge of `kind`. If one follows that argument, one could implement a solution like this:

```
type Reply = { kind: "loginReply", t: LoginReply } | { kind: "logoutReply", t: LogoutReply }

type LoginReply = { kind: "loginSucceeded", t: LoginSucceeded } | { kind: "alreadyLoggedIn", t: AlreadyLoggedIn }

interface LoginSucceeded {
}

interface AlreadyLoggedIn {
    loggedInUsername: string;
}

interface LogoutReply {
    logout: boolean
}

function doStuff(o: Reply) {
    switch(o.kind)
    {
        case 'loginReply' : o.t; // is LoginReply
            const loginReply = o.t;
            switch(loginReply.kind) {
                case 'alreadyLoggedIn' : loginReply.t; /* is AlreadyLoggedIn */ break;
                case 'loginSucceeded' : loginReply.t; /* is LoginSucceeded */ break;
            }
            break;
        case 'logoutReply': o.t; // LogoutReply
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `LoginReply` is just a union of `LoginSucceeded | AlreadyLoggedIn`, from the type system perspective there is no difference between `type Reply = LoginReply | LogoutReply` and `type Reply = LoginSucceeded | AlreadyLoggedIn | LogoutReply`. The `type` keyword introduces a type alias which as the name suggests is just a convenient name for the type not a new type in itself.

You have two options, neither of them 100% what you want.

You can check all possible values `kind` of `LoginReply` as you mentioned you considered:

```
function doStuff(o: Reply) {
    switch(o.kind)
    {
        case 'alreadyLoggedIn' : 
        case 'loginSucceeded' : 
            o; /* is LoginReply */ break;
        case 'logoutReply': o // o is  LogoutReply
    }
}
```

Or you can add an extra `subKind` field for the `LoginReply` subtypes:

```
export type Reply = LoginReply | LogoutReply

type LoginReply = LoginSucceeded | AlreadyLoggedIn

interface LoginSucceeded {
    subKind: "loginSucceeded";
    kind: "loginReply";
}

interface AlreadyLoggedIn {
    kind: "loginReply";
    subKind: "alreadyLoggedIn";
    loggedInUsername: string;
}

interface LogoutReply {
    kind: "logoutReply";
    logout: boolean
}

function doStuff(o: Reply) {
    switch(o.kind)
    {
        case 'loginReply' : o // is LoginReply
            switch(o.subKind) {
                case 'alreadyLoggedIn' : o; /* is AlreadyLoggedIn */ break;
                case 'loginSucceeded' : o; /* is LoginSucceeded */ break;
            }
            break;
        case 'logoutReply': o // LogoutReply
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thought of a third one, you may be interested in it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758043/6690391